# How to work with Tables in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Good Day, I have a table in crystal report and when I run it, the following is the results:
[image]

I am trying to code the samething in SSRS, but I have the following questions:

1. How do I make only the first row of the results to be bold shown?
2. How do I make the source info (last column) to not appear for a specific status (stooped) in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a table header section. The captions in there can be formatted independently from the rest of the table.

You can either make the SQL command used to collect the information so that it does not it fills the underlying column for "Source Info" only if there status requires it. Alternatively you can use an expression for the column that either assigns the value of the database result or an empty string depending on the status.

Comment: =iif(Fields!Status.Value="Something", Fields!SourceInfo.Value, "")

Comment: in which field do I put this expression? Status or SourceInfo?

Comment: SourceInfo, because that is where you want to hide the value conditionally.

Comment: can you please advise on what I need to do if there is already an expression in there? Like I want to use two different expression in this same textbox

Comment: Depends on what the other expression is.

Answer (score 0):

1) In the design of the table in the rdl you could add any formatting to the text in the header or the content, font size, type, weight, etc.

2)  You could use the visibility property of the row in the rdl to show or hide the row depending on an external parameter or a value in the data:

```
 =iif(Fields!Data.Value="Example", true ,false)
```

So this property will hide the row if the Data field is "Example".